# Starting vms in batches of 5 in parallel

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a set if VM in Azure and needs to start the VMS in a batch in parallel. For example I have 100 vm, I need a batch of 1-5 vm first start in parallel, then the next from 6-10, and so forth. I am able to start all the vms in parallel - but I can't find a way of adding limits in the foreach statement

```
foreach ($vm in ($vms | Select-Object 5))
```

Any suggestion of how I can do that?

```
$vms = Get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "VmList" 
#$jobs = @()

foreach ($vm in ($vms | Select-Object 5))
{
    $params = @($vm.Name)

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        param($ComputerName)
        start-Azvm -Name $ComputerName -ResourceGroupName "VmList"
    } -ArgumentList $params 
}

# Wait for it all to complete
Wait-Job -Job $job

# Getting the information back from the jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep track yourself you could use splatting on `Select-Object`. Starting with `-Skip 0 -First 5`, increment skip so the next loop would be `-Skip 5 -First 5` and so on.

```
$vms = Get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "VmList" 

$batch = @{
    Skip  = 0
    First = 5
}

Do
{
    foreach ($vm in ($vms | Select-Object @batch))
    {
        $params = @($vm.Name)
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            param($ComputerName)
            start-Azvm -Name $ComputerName -ResourceGroupName "VmList"
        } -ArgumentList $params 
    }

    # Wait for it all to complete
    Wait-Job -Job $job

    # Getting the information back from the jobs
    Get-Job | Receive-Job

    $batch.Skip += 5
}
until($batch.skip -ge $vms.count)
```